# Which one of these geometry proofs are incorrect?

Tags: geometry, fake-proofs

One proof proves an angle to be 90º, and the other proof proves the very same angle to be 60º. I've looked over both proofs several times but I can't find what the error in either one of them is. And they obviously can't *both* be correct.

Below are two pictures from my notebook. One states the problem itself and exactly what type of shapes and angles we're dealing with. The first picture also shows the first proof in two column format. The second picture shows the second proof also in two column format.

Can anybody spot a problem with either one of these?

EDIT: Just to be clear I actually don't know what the problem with one of these proofs is. That's why I'm asking. Both seem like they should work to me, yet they yield contradicting conclusions.

[image]

[image]

Initial Problem

Given the following:

- $ABCD$ is a square
- $\overline{FG}$ is a perpendicular bisector of $\overline{BG}$
- $\newcommand{arc}[1]{\stackrel{\Large\frown}{#1}}\arc{AC}$ is part of a circle centered at $B$
- Points $E$, $A$, and $C$ all lie on circle $B$

Find $m\angle BEC$

Proof that $m\angle BEC=60^\circ$

$\begin{aligned}
& &&\text{Statement} &&\text{Reason}\\
&1. &&\overline{BG}≅\overline{GC} &&\text{Given}\\
&2. &&m<CGE=90^\circ &&\text{Given}\\
&3. &&m\angle BGE=90^\circ &&\text{Given}\\
&4. &&\overline{EG}≅\overline{FG} &&\text{Reflexive property}\\
&5. &&\triangle CGE≅\triangle BGE &&\text{SAS}\\
&6. &&\overline{BE}≅\overline{CE} &&\text{Because of $5$}\\
&7. &&\text{Both $\overline{BE}$ and $\overline{BG}$ are radii of circle $B$} &&\text{Both $E$ and $C$ lie on circle $B$ and point $B$ is the origin of circle $B$}\\
&8. &&\therefore \overline{BC}≅\overline{BE} &&\text{The radius of the same circle remains constant}\\
&9. &&\overline{BC}≅ EC &&\text{Transitive property}\\
&10. &&\triangle BEC\text{ is equilateral} &&8\text{ and }9\\
&11. &&m\angle BEC = 60^\circ &&\text{All angles in an equilateral triangle are $60^\circ$}\\
&&&\text{Q.E.D.}
\end{aligned}$

[image]

Proof that $m\angle BEC=90^\circ$

$\begin{aligned}
& &&\text{Statement} &&\text{Reason}\\
&1. &&\text{construct line $\overline{HI}$ such that $\overline{HI}⟂\overline{AB}$ and point $E$ is collinear to $\overline{HI}$} &&\text{None}\\
&2. &&m<CGE\text{ and } m\angle BGE\text{ are $90^\circ$} &&\text{Given}\\
&3. &&\overline{CG}≅\overline{BG} &&\text{Given}\\
&4. &&\overline{EG}≅\overline{EG} &&\text{Reflexive property}\\
&5. &&\triangle CGE ≅ \triangle BGE &&\text{SAS}\\
&6. &&\overline{HE}≅\overline{BG} &&\text{Because of how we constructed $\overline{HI}$}\\
&7. &&\overline{HB}≅\overline{EG} &&\text{Same reason as $6$}\\
&8. &&m\angle EGB=90^\circ &&\text{Same reason as $6$}\\
&9. &&\triangle GEB≅\triangle HEB &&\text{SAS}\\
&10. &&m\angle HEB = m\angle GEB &&\text{Statement $9$}\\
&11. &&m\angle HEG = 90^\circ &&\text{Same reason as $6$}\\
&12. &&m\angle HEB + m\angle GEB = 90^\circ &&\text{None}\\
&13. &&2(m\angle HEB)= 90^\circ&&\text{Statement $10$}\\
&14. &&m\angle HEB= 45^\circ&&\text{None}\\
&15. &&m\angle BEG= 45^\circ&&\text{Statement $10$}\\
&16. &&m\angle CEG= 45^\circ&&\text{Statement $5$}\\
& &&\therefore m\angle BEC = m\angle CEG + m\angle BEG = 45^\circ + 45 ^\circ =90^\circ&&\\
&&&\text{Q.E.D.}
\end{aligned}$

[Image of first page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/64GL2.jpg)
[Image of second page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ulfdH.jpg)

Comment: While you show a good deal of work, at least in the future consider putting it in MathJax to be more easily readable... I for one struggle a bit in a few places with your handwriting. Not that I am sure how you would convert the two column proof style... I would generally consider it poor form anyway, and would recommend reducing any redundancy (i.e. empty lines, or "cuz math"). Regardless, a well intended question with good effort!

Comment: Have you tried graphing this and actually checking btw?

Comment: Hey thanks for the suggestion and no I was just about to try graphing. But thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: In case you want a visual, https://imgur.com/a/gebOT0c

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You made a mistake in statement (9) of the second exercise. If you apply SAS to $\triangle BEH$ and $\triangle EBG$, you obtain that $\angle BEG=\angle EBH$ and $\angle GBE=\angle BEH$.

Answer (score 4):

You can see that $\angle BEC$ cannot be $90^o$ as follows.

Assume $\angle BEC = 90^o$. $BE$ is a radius of the circle through $A$, $E$ and $C$, so $EC$ must be a tangent to this circle (angle between radius and tangent of a circle is always $90^o$). But a tangent to a  circle only intersects a circle once, whereas line $EC$ intersects the circle at two distinct points, $E$ and $C$. This is a contradiction. Therefore our initial assumption that $\angle BEC = 90^o$ must be incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

Because a picture is worth a thousand words, here is a visual reason why $\angle BEC \neq 90^{\circ}$

[image]

Comment: This might be useful as a heuristic, illustrative tool but I don't think it really lends itself to a proof. Perhaps you could add some more text for justification.

Comment: @Jam While I would generally disagree with you (once one appreciates the geometry at hand, the problem becomes much easier and errors are easier to spot), I feel this is beside the point - I don't *intend* for this answer to be a proof, merely a heuristic! The other answers point out the issue with the step. This isn't intended to supersede those answers, merely to add to them. I would absolutely recommend the OP accept one of the other posts - I merely thought the OP might appreciate the intuition

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen And I do actually, this visual really helped me out because I can see exactly why 90º wouldn't work. Thanks!

Comment: @AidanJalili You're welcome! Glad to hear the visual could be of help :)